# Asynchronous VuexFire Data Fetch With Then/Catch

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuexfire

Given the following functioning vuex action named `init` that fetches a `settings` and an `accounts` collection:

```
actions: {
  init: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, commit }, payload) => {
    bindFirestoreRef(
      'settings', fb.settings.doc(payload),
    )
      .then(() => commit('SETTINGS_READY', true))
      .catch((err) => {
        commit('SNACKBAR_TEXT', err.message);
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      });

    bindFirestoreRef(
      'accounts', fb.accounts.where('program', '==', payload),
    )
      .then(() => commit('ACCOUNTS_READY', true))
      .catch((err) => {
        commit('SNACKBAR_TEXT', err.message);
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      });
  }),
},
```

I have two questions:

1. The code appears to run synchronously, but I want the two collections to be fetched asynchronously to maximize performance. How can that be achieved?
2. Is it possible to refactor this code to be more concise and yet provide for the independent (and synchronous) `then/catch` functionality present in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` / `await` function then call the `bindFirestoreRef` inside `Promise` constructor.

```
actions: {
init: firestoreAction(async ({ bindFirestoreRef, commit }, payload) => {
    await Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bindFirestoreRef('settings', fb.settings.doc(payload))
        .then((res) => {
          commit('SETTINGS_READY', true);
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          commit('SNACKBAR_TEXT', err.message)
          Sentry.captureException(err)
          reject(err)
        })
    })

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bindFirestoreRef('accounts', fb.accounts.where('program', '==', payload))
        .then((res) => {
          commit('ACCOUNTS_READY', true);
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          commit('SNACKBAR_TEXT', err.message)
          Sentry.captureException(err)
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }) 
},
```

Comment: I considered using `async/await` earlier but thought the second `await` would synchronously wait for the first `await` to resolve. Does the use of `new Promise` with `await` change that and allow the two awaits to be asynchronous instead?

Comment: I was able to test this code and it seems to also be synchronous at the `await` level, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ßiansor Å. Ålmerol, would you be willing to take a look at another Vuexfire issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903702/how-to-use-moment-js-with-vuexfire